# Grafana Publix Dashboard: Data Source not found

Tags: grafana, dashboard

I am trying to use Grafana public Dashboards. First some infos:

- Grafana Version Grafana v10.1.5 (849c612fcb) running in a Docker container
- InfluxDB as data source (its a remote data source running on another server)

1. I created a simple dashboard, no template variables, no complex queries. While logged in, the dashboard works as expected.
2. I made the dashboard public using the functionality described here: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/dashboard-public/
3. When loading the dashboard, all 3 requests to the data source fail. The developer console shows "500 internal server error"s.
4. the server logs have some more info:

```
logger=publicdashboards.service t=2023-10-17T11:08:39.17688086Z level=error msg="Error querying datasources for public dashboard" error="data source not found" datasources=[influxdb]

logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin t=2023-10-17T11:08:39.17693254Z level=error msg= error="unexpected error type [*errors.errorString]: data source not found" remote_addr=213.182.3.4 traceID=

logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin t=2023-10-17T11:08:39.17697267Z level=error msg="Request Completed" method=POST path=/api/public/dashboards/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/panels/2/query status=500 remote_addr=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx time_ms=1 duration=1.949332ms size=48 referer=https://fuerstenschulepublic.cs.egrid.de/public-dashboards/7b648abef11d43b9974baf863a772c06?orgId=1&refresh=10s
```

As of now, I have no idea where to further debug this problem. Do you have any ideas what the issue could be?

Thanks & best regards

Philipp

Comment: Feature you are trying to use as of now is in public preview. There is a good chance it's a bug or you missed some undocumented required step or something like this. Consider creating an issue in the Grafana's repo or their community forum.

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of the problem: I copy pasted the Dashboard definition from another Grafana Instance. I re-created the Dashboard on the new Instance and it works :) I did not check yet which part of the dashboard JSON causes the issue. If I find it, I will post it here. –